# Adding subview on the top of annotation callout

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

In the showcallout part that is placeholder for address, title subtitle in annotations, is there a way to add subview? What I want is to put  small rectangle on the top of this box(callout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this app - https://github.com/akshay1188/CustomAnnotation